# Deeplinking links to launcher/main activity instead of the deeplinked one

Tags: android, android-activity, deep-linking, activity-lifecycle

When accessing the deeplink while the app is in the background the correct `PostActivity` is launched and stacked on top of the activity the deeplink was called from. This is good and correct.

If the app is not open in the background when the deeplink is tapped the launcher activity is opened instead of the deeplink-associated activity. Strangely, if the back button is pressed to close the stacked launcher activity and the deeplink is tapped again the correct `PostActivity` is launched.

- Is there an explanation for this behaviour?
- Is this expected behaviour?
- How do I always have the deeplinked activity launched on tapping deeplinks and not the launcher activity?

My launcher activity is:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

My deeplinked activity is:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".PostActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="@string/deeplink_scheme" />
            <data android:host="article" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Find this hard to believe. Android will not start `SplashActivity` by itself. Are you sure you don't have some code in `PostActivity` that checks if the app has been initialized and if not, redirects to `SplashActivity`? Please post the code from `PostActivity.onCreate()`.

Comment: Thanks. I guess that answers if it's "expected behaviour" which is probably the input I needed. It may be what you suggest, so I'm going to create a new blank project to test the 'issue' before digging about in my existing project.

Comment: I tried a new project with a simple deeplink and two activities, and it all works fine. My issue must be project-specific and not at all normal behaviour.

Comment: Did you find any solution? what was the problem exactly? @Wex

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that it's not normal behaviour, there must be something other than the obvious which is specific to this project that's causing this to occur.